# Hybrid web view crashes after back button is pressed (Android)

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xlabs

I'm using [HybridWebView](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/HybridWebView) and whenever I try to pressed back on the Android hardware button, the app crashes, when I press on the action bar, the expected back action is performed.

There is also an [open issue on Git Hub](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/740) regarding a similar issue, without any fix yet.

This is my stack trace:

```
at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native method)  
at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:29)  
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)  
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(Native method)  
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)  
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)  
Pending exception android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable thrown by 'void mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run():-2'
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
 (22346): art/runtime/runtime.cc:284]     
at Consumer.Mobile.Views.RedirectPage.OnBackButtonPressed () [0x00001] in ~\Views\RedirectPage.xaml.cs:66 
at Xamarin.Forms.Page.SendBackButtonPressed () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
at Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.OnBackButtonPressed () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
at Xamarin.Forms.Page.SendBackButtonPressed () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.HandleBackPressed (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:   
 at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity.OnBackPressed () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
at XLabs.Forms.XFormsApplicationDroid.<>n__FabricatedMethod5 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
at XLabs.Forms.XFormsApplicationDroid+<OnBackPressed>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   
at void mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run() (RunnableImplementor.java:-2)  
 at void mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run() (RunnableImplementor.java:29)  
at void android.os.Handler.handleCallback(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:739)
```

Comment: I was unable to reproduce the error so more info would be needed.

Comment: I'm using xlabs version 2.0.5540.30732